# UpdatePanel inside a bootstrap modal doesn't update

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, updatepanel

I change the label's text that resides with a UpdatePanel that is within a Bootstrap Modal. When the Modal pops up, the text has not been set (through in debugging I can see it sets the labels text correctly with the error message).

This modal resides and is called from within a UserControl.

What am I missing? Why isn't the UpdatePanel being triggered?

```
<%--ERROR MODAL--%>
<asp:Panel runat="server" class="modal fade" ID="modalErrorMessage" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalErrorMessage" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-content panel-danger">
                <div class="modal-header panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Error!</div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblmodalErrorMessage" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <div class="modal-footer margin-top-sm">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

```
    Private Sub RaiseErrorMessageModal(errorMessage As String)
        lblmodalErrorMessage.Text = errorMessage
        RegisterModalPopup(modalErrorMessage.ClientID)
    End Sub



    Protected Sub RegisterModalPopup(modalId As String)
        Dim script = String.Format("$('#{0}').modal();", modalId)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), modalId,
                                            script, True)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify an `ID` for your `UpdatePanel` and also set the `UpdateMode` property to indicate how the update panel should update/refresh its content.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel123" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

In your code where you set the text of the `Label` you should call the `.Update()` event of the `UpdatePanel`:

```
//Depending on where this code is, you may need to find your UpdatePanel control.
Private Sub RaiseErrorMessageModal(errorMessage As String)
    lblmodalErrorMessage.Text = errorMessage
    UpdatePanel123.Update()
    RegisterModalPopup(modalErrorMessage.ClientID)
End Sub
```

**MSDN reference**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My understanding is that an UpdatePanel defaults to Update Mode = always . And then because it's set to always that a modification to its contents would trigger an update , is this incorrect?

Comment: That is true to a point, however, there is no event registered for the changing of your textboxes content. You would need to call this update from your code-behind. If your `RaiseErrorMessageModal` method is being called by a control, you could specify that in the `Triggers` markup of your `UpdatePanel` as an alternative.

Comment: @JackReilly can you let us know if the answer has resolved your issue or what the outcome was. Marking replies that answered your question will help future users.

Comment: I did it exactly how you said and it has the same issue. The text is set correctly, seen during debugging, then the update is called and then the modal registered, and the text is not changed. It's still not being updated.